# Does primary, secondary, tertiary, [...] continue forever?

Tags: numbers

[What follows next in the sequence "unary, binary, ternary..."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25116/what-follows-next-in-the-sequence-unary-binary-ternary) gives a lengthy list up to 12 for the sequence "primary, secondary, tertiary, [...]". Does this naming continue forever? If so, what is the pattern?

Comment: There is no limit to ordinal numbers, no.  But unless it’s something like *centennial* or *millennial*, you’re just going to baffle people with tongue-twisters like *quinquagesimal, sexagesimal, quingentensimal,* and the rest. There is no reason not to use English for all these.

Comment: The series is constructed from [Latin prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_%28linguistics%29).

Comment: [See here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/60405.html) for how to construct these. But if you start calling base64 *sexagesimoquaternary*, people will hate you. :)

Comment: There's ***n-ary*** go figure. "Adjective (mathematics) of, or relating to, n entities (where n is an arbitrary or large number)" http://www.yourdictionary.com/n-ary See also: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/n-ary

Comment: @tchrist Disappointingly though, that doesn't answer if there's an end to the list.

Comment: If an arbitrary number of any size can be shown to have an ordinal English construction, then there is no limit. Per Kris' example, the *-ary* suffix means that any cardinal number can be provisioned as ordinal. Then again, ((2^1024)-3)ary vs ((2^1024)-4)ary would be relevant to whom?

Answer (score 5):

The rules for forming these words are here [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171227154944/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/60405.html) (as noted above) and they are indeed based on Latin.

Comment: Well deserved upvote, but ... is there a less tenuous link? The given one goes to the wayback machine because the original link is dead, and that link references a dead link as its source. Anyone?