# Counting with arities

Tags: adjectives, count

The Wikipedia entry for [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) lists a sequence of adjectives meaning *in group of (a particular number of elements)*. When referring to numbers between 0 and 10, the *-ary* adjectives are:

- 0 - nullary
- 1 - unary
- 2 - binary
- 3 - ternary
- 4 - quaternary
- 5 - quinary
- 6 - senary
- 7 - septenary
- 8 - octonary or octary
- 9 - novenary or nonary
- 10 - decenery or denary

Can this sequence be continued? What are the rules (if any) to form the adjective meaning n-*ary* (in group of *n*)?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25116/what-follows-next-in-the-sequence-unary-binary-ternary)?

Answer (score 3):

You weren't so far from a slightly broader answer when you were on Wikipedia. http://exampleproblems.com/wiki/index.php/Arity lists a couple not mentioned above:

- 0 - nullary or anary - 0
- ⋮
- 11 - undenary
- 12 - duodenary
- 20 - vigesary
- 100 - centenary
- 1000 - millenary

Otherwise, I guess you're stuck with n-ary.

I don't know if terms for other *irregul*-arities combine: is there a "unvigesary" for 21 or "duovigesary" for 22 or other arbitrary combinations of number roots from ancient languages?

Comment: +1 for "*irregul*-arities" :-)