# What is the word for base-64?

Tags: single-word-requests

The **base-2** numbering system is called ***binary***.

The **base-8** numbering system is called ***octal***.

The **base-10** numbering system is called ***decimal***.

The **base-16** numbering system is called ***hexadecimal***.

How should the **base-64** numbering system be called?

(A word of Latin origin like the above would be nice.)

Comment: More specifically, see this answer: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/120187/191178

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I voted to open it in error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be "*Tetrasexagesimal*". Here is a great number of the bases named: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems).

*"Tetra*" stands for the final "4" according to this system; "*sexagesimal*" stands for "60".

Comment: So much more convenient than saying "base-64" :)

Comment: @user888379 For the sake of completeness it is still justifiable, but, of course, even with respect to that criterion, the naming—which _has_ to stop somewhere— might have stopped at "hexadecimal", which is nevertheless very commonly used, surprisingly maybe, enormously more than "base 64".  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hexadecimal%2Cbase+64&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chexadecimal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbase%2064%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @user888379 it may not be as convenient, but it is certainly far more erudite.

Comment: @MikeNakis I understand your concern for the systematization  of concept labelling, but I still think that somehow (perhaps unknowingly) you indulge in a divergence from what true erudition is, and that is, I believe, essentially, pure knowledge of a relatively important proportion of the concepts pertaining to a given field, and not a matter of what system you use to identify those concepts.

Comment: @LPH In practice, "hexadecimal" decays pretty quickly to "hex". There's never been any ambiguity in my experience.

Comment: @user888379 The result in the ngram  mentioned above amounts to  approximately the same thing if it were the correct but it is wrong; this is the correct one: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hexadecimal%2Cbase+16&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chexadecimal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbase%2016%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chexadecimal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbase%2016%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @LPH The pedantry that I'm prone to is saying "radix" rather than "base".

Comment: @user888379 Personally, I wouldn't call it pedantry, and I tend to agree with this trend: there is at least one other concept in mathematics that uses the word "base" (the base set in the theory of mathematical structures); as long as adopting a new form makes for the diversity of the forms used, it seems to me that the practice is commendable; if, on top of that the new form has a particular semantically catchy quirk which is missing in the former term—as is the case for radix  (radix, root, inverse of raising to a power)—it's all for the better, in my opinion.